# RNN with numeric data in SKFLOW

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I want to try an SKFLOW recurrent neural network on some time sequence data with real values for a binary classification problem. Each row of my data contains 57 features (variables) and I would like to look at the previous 2 samples and the next 2 samples to make predictions on each row.

My data looks like this:

sample -2: f1, f2, f3, f4,...f57, sample -1: f1, f2, f3, f4,...f57, current sample: f1, f2, f3, f4,...f57, sample +1: f1, f2, f3, f4,...f57, sample +2: f1, f2, f3, f4,...f57

I started with the [SKFLOW example RNN for text classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/examples/text_classification_builtin_rnn_model.py).

```
MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH = 10

vocab_processor = skflow.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH)
X_train = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(X_train)))
X_test = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(X_test)))

n_words = len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
print('Total words: %d' % n_words)

### Models

EMBEDDING_SIZE = 50

# Customized function to transform batched X into embeddings
def input_op_fn(X):
    # Convert indexes of words into embeddings.
    # This creates embeddings matrix of [n_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE] and then
    # maps word indexes of the sequence into [batch_size, sequence_length,
    # EMBEDDING_SIZE].
    word_vectors = skflow.ops.categorical_variable(X, n_classes=n_words,
        embedding_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, name='words')
    # Split into list of embedding per word, while removing doc length dim.
    # word_list results to be a list of tensors [batch_size, EMBEDDING_SIZE].
    word_list = skflow.ops.split_squeeze(1, MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH, word_vectors)
    return word_list

# Single direction GRU with a single layer
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowRNNClassifier(rnn_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, 
    n_classes=15, cell_type='gru', input_op_fn=input_op_fn,
    num_layers=1, bidirectional=False, sequence_length=None,
    steps=1000, optimizer='Adam', learning_rate=0.01, continue_training=True)
```

It looks as if I should be able to just modify the input_op_fn to make it work but I am not sure how to correctly convert my numpy array to a tensor for the skflow.TensorFlowRNNClassifier. This is what it looks like for the text classification example.

```
>>> word_vectors.get_shape() 

TensorShape([Dimension(560000), Dimension(10), Dimension(50)])

>>> len(word_list)

10
```

If I am interpreting the text problem correctly then for my problem it would be 
TensorShape([Dimension(# rows), Dimension(57), Dimension(3)])

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [unit test](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/skflow/tests/test_nonlinear.py#L61) for RNN.

Suppose this is the numeric data:

        `data = np.array(list([[2, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                              [2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                              [3, 3, 1, 2, 1],
                              [2, 4, 5, 4, 1]]), dtype=np.float32)
        labels = np.array(list([1, 0, 1, 0]), dtype=np.float32)`

`data` is of shape `(4, 5)` where 4 is batch_size and 5 is the sequence_length. Then you want to have `tf.split(1, 5, X)` in `input_op_fn()`. Hope this helps. You are welcomed to submit an PR for adding an example dealing with this.

Comment: This was a big help. However, the testBidirectionalRNN generated an error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bidirectional'

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. Which version are you using? From Github or from PyPI?

Comment: I think you are using an older version. Can you `sudo pip uninstall skflow` and then `sudo pip install skflow`? I just tested it on my end and it worked.

Comment: I am on Mac. I will try it on Linux later. My version on Mac is skflow-0.1.0.

Comment: Yeah if you use the most recent version from PyPI, it should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: After reinstalling a couple of times, the bidirectional is working but I am getting a different error from the unit test. I posted an issue at the skflow github page. https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/issues/106

Comment: Thanks. We will take a look at it soon.

Comment: @denson This should be fixed now. Try the most updated version. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I have it working now but I am still getting a worse result on my data with RNN and LSTM than the standard DNN.

Comment: I am glad it worked! This really depends on the application and data set. Some data sets are not suitable for RNN/LSTM.